# Include html pages in a php file

Tags: php, html

I would like to create a template using html and css so I created the following template.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Application</title>
<link href="CSS/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src=""></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <!--<div class="header_left"></div>
        <div class="header_right"> -->
            <h3>Application</h3>
            <h4>****  Project ****</h4>

    </div>
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul class="mainnavbar">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Description</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mainbody">
        <div class="leftcol">
            <div class="left_navbar">
                <ul class="left_inner">
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Description</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact me</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="midcol">
            Center
        </div>
        <div class="rightcol">
            Right Column
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Designed By <a href="">Me</a></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Because I want to create a dynamic website I want to separate this template.html into index.php, header.php, navbar.php, home.php and footer.php. So I did the following:

**index.php**

```
<?php
include("includes/header.html");
include("includes/navbar.html");
include("includes/home.html");
include("includes/footer.html");
?>
```

**header.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Application</title>
<link href="CSS/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src=""></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <!--<div class="header_left"></div>
        <div class="header_right"> -->
        <h3>Application</h3>
        <h4>****Project ****</h4>
    </div>
```

**navbar.html**

```
<div class="navbar">
<ul class="mainnavbar">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="login.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Description</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**home.html**

```
<div class="mainbody">
<div class="leftcol">
    <div class="left_navbar">
        <ul class="left_inner">
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Description</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="midcol">
    Center
</div>
<div class="rightcol">
    Right Column
</div>
</div>
```

**footer.html**

```
<div class="footer">Designed By <a href="">me</a></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have these files in a folder called includes. I just separated the file template.html in 4 html files and then called them from index.php, but I just get a white page when I run index.php in the browsers. Is there something missing?

Comment: include is not a function, use `include "includes/header.html"`

Comment: You can use it like a function.

Comment: @koala_dev: are u sure that this syntax is incorrect `include("file")`

Comment: @Akam that syntax is correct

Comment: yes you're right, it is valid to use it like that, sorry

Comment: You should check the include_path. Also, did you check the webserver's log file when you visit the page? That should give you some pointers

Comment: add this line to top of `index.php`: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Do what Akam said, and also make sure your webserver is running PHP.  Does a file with just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` output a bunch of stuff about PHP?

Comment: @cincodenada Maybe you are right. I tried phpinfo and I have blank page. So the problem is the server? I try to do this page in localhost and I have WAMPSERVER which is running.

Comment: If phpinfo (or, more basic, `<?php echo "Hello, world!" ?>` isn't working, then you've got a problem with your server configuration.  I don't know enough about WAMPSERVER to be helpful, but that's where you'll want to look.

Comment: You also could use *require* instead of *include* to force error dumping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your code (syntax and idea with including html) is fine. That should work.**

You have to search for problems somewhere else.

Maybe you have a problem with:

- web server configuration (virtual hosts, directories etc.)
- wrong url / wrong server (refreshing some web server url, but you work on local XAMPP)
- file permissions (however apache normally should report error in that case)

**Looking at web server error logs may help.**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't just running your `template.html` just by opening it locally in a browser.

Since [PHP](http://www.php.net/) is a [server side language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting), you would need to run the page on a live server on a local server such as [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/). [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) is also a nice tool when locally developing sites that require PHP.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use `file_get_contents("path_to_file/file.html")` instead of `include()`

But only if there is HTML content, not PHP

Comment: If you use file_get_contents you'll have to also do something with those contents (echo for instance)

Comment: You *can*, but it's not what `file_get_contents()` was intended for, and it's a poor choice when `include()` exists to do exactly this.